# Renaming CVT Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just posted a question about CVT on the main site and have noticed the following:

- there is a generic tag called [transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transmission)
- there's a [manual-transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual-transmission)
- there's an [automatic-transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-transmission)
- there's a [cvt](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvt)

Just to make the CVT tag more likely to be found by relevant posters, can we/should we rename it to "cvt-transmission" to match the format of the other 2 specific tags?

Comment: Just a comment: it would match the other formatting, but do remember that technically speaking that would make the new tag mean "Continual Variable Transmission Transmission."  Don't think it's a serious objection; just throwing it out there to chew on.

Comment: @anonymous2 I agree, but most people use the word CVT as a buzzword, not as an acronym. :)

Comment: Absolutely true.  Like I said, it's not a serious objection; I just thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't agree more and believe it would be a good move. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: We need a mod to do this. So what you are saying is that if either of us gets elected, this will be the first order of business? :)

Comment: @tlhIngan - Actually, no we don't. I already did the duty. "cvt" exists, right now, there's no questions against it. They've all been moved over to a new tag.

Comment: @Paulster. Thanks a million!

Comment: @tlhIngan - Nothing you couldn't do for yourself :o)

Comment: @Paulster Don't think I have the powa', not yet at least. :) I can edit tag descriptions, but not tag names. Or is there some special magical place I need to go to edit tag names?

Comment: @tlhIngan - All I did was click on the cvt tag, edit the first question which popped up, then create the new tag and delete the old tag from the question. I then went through and edited each of the remaining 8 questions, putting the new tag in place and deleting the unwanted tag. Like I said, nothing you could just do if you needed to. Fairly simple, but laborious task.

Comment: @Paulster This is silly. I'm sure the REAL mods have a tool for this. :)

Comment: @tlhIngan - I'm sure they do, but whatever it takes to get the job done, it gets done.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Just in case you haven't figured it out already, it's done through tag synonyms. Create a synonym, then swap them, then delete the old tag if desired. Bonus points for not bumping every question with the tag onto the front page. (Not a big deal with 9 questions, but with tags that have seen a lot of use, this could be a major consideration.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Would that work without it actually making it to be a tag synonym? I've attempted (as a regular user) to create tag synonyms in the past. Never makes it to the second vote.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 With a diamond you can do it all by yourself. Tag synonyms was the quickest way I found to actually rename a tag (I've held a diamond on [ham.se] and [worldbuilding.se]), but I'd say feel free to bring it up in TL if you are wondering if some other method has been implemented recently. That's what that chat room is there for...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I was actually wondering for just a regular user. I know I got the all powerful Bob Cross hammer now ... haha. And I'm in the TL regularly, so am familiar.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Indeed, as an ordinary (even high-rep) user, it's a lot more involved.

Answer (score 4):

Done
[CVT is now a Tag Synonym of CVT-Transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/cvt-transmission/synonyms), so no one can create a CVT tag

Comment: Good  call and thanks.